# SQL error when try to create new table

Tags: postgresql

Already I have only one table 'category' with 'id_category', 'rgt' and 'lft' columns.

When I try to create Table:

```
 CREATE TABLE category_translation(
  id_category_translation int NOT NULL,
  id_category int NOT NULL,
  language_code varchar(5) NOT NULL,
  title varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  description varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id_category_translation),
  KEY id_category (id_category),
  CONSTRAINT category_translation_ibfk_1
  FOREIGN KEY (id_category)
  REFERENCES category (id_category)
  ON DELETE CASCADE
)
```

This error showing up:

```
ERROR:  type "id_category" does not exist
LINE 8:   KEY id_category (id_category),
              ^
```

Comment: It is unclear what you are trying to do here. You want a trigger on table `category`, fine. (Note the difference between a `trigger` and a `trigger function`, you seem to mix them up.) But what is that trigger supposed to do? Delete corresponding records in `category_translation`? Please edit your question to make clear what you want to achieve.

Comment: @Patrick sorry, I mistakenly pasted a completely different code

Comment: @GrzegorzNowak Have you got correct Trigger?? I was trying to answer it :D

Comment: @WingedPanther http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28059706/sql-error-when-trying-to-create-new-trigger

Comment: Where in the manual did you find that syntax `KEY (...)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume the `key` in `KEY id_category (id_category),` is intended to be a unique index. Here is an example of what you might need:

```
create table category
    (
        id_category int primary key
    ) ;
create table category_translation
    (
        id_category_translation int primary key
          , id_category int unique constraint category_translation_ibfk_1 references category on delete cascade
          , language_code varchar(5) not null
          , title varchar(100) not null
          , description varchar(255) not null
    ) ;
```