# SQL error when trying to create new trigger

Tags: postgresql, triggers

And when I try to create a trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER ctg_el_del 
AFTER DELETE ON ctg
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
DELETE FROM ctg
       where ctg.id_ctg = old.lft
            WHERE  cat.id_ctg = old.rgt;
END;
```

This error showing up:

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "BEGIN"
LINE 4: BEGIN
        ^
```

Comment: Your _delete_ script is incorrect you need to use _AND_ after the first _Where_ clause

Comment: Check the manual, it's all documented there including examples: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-trigger.html#PLPGSQL-TRIGGER-EXAMPLE

Answer (score 2):

**STEP 1 :**   You need to Create function that returns type Trigger in that function you should mention the SQL Operation like below:

```
CREATE FUNCTION trigger_function() RETURNS TRIGGER AS $$
BEGIN
    DELETE FROM ctg 
    WHERE ctg.id_ctg = old.lft
    AND   ctg.id_ctg = old.rgt;
END
$$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

**STEP 2 :** And then create the trigger on the table to call after delete like this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER ctg_el_del 
AFTER DELETE ON ctg
FOR EACH ROW
EXECUTE PROCEDURE trigger_function();
```

Comment: @GrzegorzNowak if you;re using the psql command line add a `;` after each query.

Comment: When i try to delete element i got error: `ERROR:  control reached end of trigger procedure without RETURN
CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function trigger_function()
In command:
DELETE FROM "public"."ctg" WHERE "id_ctg"='2'`

Comment: normal query for deleteing nodes with childrens is: `LOCK TABLE ctg WRITE;

SELECT @myLeft := lft, @myRight := rgt, @myWidth := rgt - lft + 1
FROM ctg
WHERE id = 3;

DELETE FROM ctg WHERE lft BETWEEN @myLeft AND @myRight;

UPDATE ctg SET rgt = rgt - @myWidth WHERE rgt > @myRight;
UPDATE ctg SET lft = lft - @myWidth WHERE lft > @myRight;

UNLOCK TABLES;`