# Is it possible to trigger a function on the database level?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table containing the following columns:

```
   id                     data
 integer       timestamp without time zone
---------      ---------------------------
    1              2015-01-26 15:41:20
..........................................
```

I also have a function (stored procedure), which needs to be triggered in the date specified by the `data` column. Is it possible to do that with `PostgreSQL 8.4` or higher?

The stored procedure has the following signature:

```
create or replace function delete_row(id integer) returns void as $$
begin
    delete from partner where id = id;
end $$
language plpgsql
```

and is going to delete the row from the table with an id passed as the parameter.

The function have to be triggered at every date existing in the data column. So if I add a new row, I also need to trigger the function in that date.

Comment: BTW, Your Question seems bit unclear for me.So just see this ans http://stackoverflow.com/a/28059741/3682599

Comment: @WingedPanther Updated. In fact I need to delete rows by date, specified in the data column.

Comment: You need to trigger this function on each INSERT ??

Comment: Ever heard about JOB? Why do u want to do it on trigger?

Comment: @WingedPanther No, I need trigger the function on each date, specified in the data in any time.

Comment: @JanWalczak No, I've not. How can I do that?

Comment: @St.Antario _The function have to be triggered at every date existing in the data column_ > When you want to do this ?? or manually do the job or in any  SQL Operations like Insert,Update,Delete ?

Answer (score 2):

Triggers don't run when a particular date happens. Loosely speaking, triggers run before or after an INSERT, UPDATE, or DELETE statement happens.

To run some code on a particular date, you would usually run an external process that periodically checks your table for a date, and then runs some other code if it finds a matching date. The external process could be controlled by `cron`, or it could be controlled by [pgAgent](http://www.pgadmin.org/docs/dev/pgagent.html).

That "some other code" could be a stored procedure (function) in the database, or it could be code written in another language that connects to the database to do its work.

Answer (score -2):

What You are explaning seems to be best done with writing SQL job in sql sever agent . It should compare actual date with date in 'data' column in your table. If actual date is greater than one in your table it should delete that row.

Do something like that:
In SQL Server Management Studio, expand the SQL Server Agent, right click on "Jobs" and select "New Job..."
in "Steps", create a "New..." one and enter this:
DELETE table WHERE data

U can change the "occurs" there to 10 sec, or 30 sec, depends on how frequently u want to check for that dates.

Comment: _In SQL Server Management Studio_ ,hey OP needs it in PostgreSQL

Comment: That's true. But maybe he can actually use that?

Comment: ***SQL Server** Management Studio* works exclusively with *SQL Server* (hence the name). So it's impossible to use this with any other DBMS